# How do I Deploy an iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, publishing, ios-provisioning

my question is actually a little more specific than this. I was asked to develop an iPhone application for my high school. I've completed said application, but I have reached the stage of publishing the app for them to use.

My school owns the $300 Enterprise license which allows them to publish in-house applications, which is what I had planned to do.

I do not have access to this Developer Account, nor a developer account, and was wondering if someone could clarify/outline the process of compiling/signing an .ipa then distributing it in-house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the person who's in charge of your school's developer program subscription. Only the "team agent" for the program can build and sign your app for distribution. If they're willing, they can also add you to their developer program team so that you can get a development certificate and access the various online documentation and other resources. You still won't be able to distribute the app by yourself, but it'll be an improvement.

The building and distribution process is described in in Apple's [Tools Workflow Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH1-SW1).

Comment: I'll ask them to add me to their Developer Program Team then. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to request for the administrator "Enterprise program" add it as a member Developer.

link with every step generation:
http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/deploy/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need access to the developer account, to get the necessary certificates and mobile provisionings to publish this app, or you'll need someone else who does have that capability to get them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following Links may help you on this:

http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad8905

[iPhone Application Enterprise Distribution Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568360/iphone-application-enterprise-distribution-process)

Hope it works for you...