# Can we install an unpublished iOS app on a remote device.?

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS app which needs to be tested in a device which is present in another country with the client. If needed I can get the UDID and other details of the device. Can I install my under-development app on that device without publishing my App.? If yes, please explain the procedure.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You have to use provisioning profile. Get device UDID and add it to your dev profile.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can. To do this you will need the UDID of all the devices where the App will be installed, and then you need to generate an Ad Hoc provisiong profile for those devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

To send the app to your client, go to XCode > Product (Menu) > Archive.

Then open Organizer > Archives (Tab) > Distribute. Follow on-screen instructions. 
This will generate an .ipa file (executable) which you can then send to your testers (through email, or whatever other mean). He will have to install this .ipa by dragging and dropping it onto iTunes.

---

**For further discussions look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154/how-do-you-beta-test-an-iphone-app?rq=1) question.**

Comment: Thanx a lot for the reply. +1 you deserve here.. :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

1)Register client's device into device list in your developer account on apples site

2)Generate Ad-Hoc provision profile and send to your client with *.ipa file

3)Test it

Also take a look at 3-rd party services like TestFlight - http://testflightapp.com .Very popular and convenient way to work with beta-testers all around the world.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is yes. You need to get UDID and add it to your developer portal as testing device. Download the provisioning profile and rebuild the app with revised provisioning profile. This app can be send to client for testing.

Comment: How will the app be send to the client.? In iOS do we get any installable file (like apk in android).?

Comment: Akshat - From xcode organizer you can export for Adhoc build where in you will get IPA file. you can email it to your client. It can be installed via itunes or iPhone configuration Utility available here. http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1466

Answer (score 0):

If you can sign with an Distribution profile for enterprises than you can upload that file on a link and user can Install the iPA file just by clicking on that link..

for more info check on these links..

[How to distribute ios application wirelessly without managing UDIDs and recompilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546581/how-to-distribute-ios-application-wirelessly-without-managing-udids-and-recompile)

[iPhone Application Enterprise Distribution Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568360/iphone-application-enterprise-distribution-process)

Answer (score -12):

This an incredibly bad idea.  What you are setting up is a back door into any iOS device to plant (potentially) malicious software. While your intentions may be good the long term effects are not.

Publishing your app would require it to go through code review, which is entail to ensure the enteritis of the app.

Comment: What the OP is requesting is required for any internal testing amongst an internal team and apple supports this practice.